# WriteVideoFrame() with Videocodec.Raw change pixel value

Tags: c#, matlab, video, ffmpeg, accord.net

I'm using Accord.Video.ffmpeg to record a video in c#. It is actually a depth video with pixels indicating the depth magnitude. From depth array I create a bitmap and the save the bitmap with WriteVideoFrame method.
Afterward, I open the video in Matlab reading frame by frame. The problem is that I have differences between the bitmap in c# and the frame in Matlab?! The difference is more or less of 10 (in a range of 255 it's a big deal)(testing at the moment if it's constant).
Since from the bitmap to videoframe I do not perform any operation I think that the problem is in the video encoder. Is is possible even though the format is Raw?!
Hints?
Alex

**UPDATE**

If I run this code in a new project everything is fine

```
unsafe private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        writerdepth.Open("testvideo.avi", 512, 424, 15, VideoCodec.Raw);
        for (int i = 0; i <depthPixels.Length; i++)
        {
            this.depthPixels[i] = (byte)100;
        }


        try
        {
            fixed (byte* p = depthPixels)
            {
                IntPtr unmanagedPointer = (IntPtr)p;
                depthbm = new Bitmap(512, 424, 512, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed, unmanagedPointer);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Errore");
        }

        writerdepth.WriteVideoFrame(depthbm);
        writerdepth.Close();
    }
}
```

going back to my code when I try to read the image instead of  RGB = [100 100 100] I have [96 94 99].
My starting code is saving depth image from kinect v2, the function is called when a new valid frame arrives.
I have no idea of the reason for this difference...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved... was the Nuget package I had version 3.4.2-alpha in the older project (strange behavior) and new 3.5.0 is the last one  (working). Updating the package solved the problem